# allrunes package installation

Tags: fonts, metafont

I got the allrunes package but it only has the metafont source. I'm on mobile so I can't build the `.tfm` files myself. I also can't use a fancier LaTeX compiler than the one I have.

Does anyone know where I can download the `.tfm`s, or if there is a way I can build them from the metafont source on an iPhone?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{allrunes}
\begin{document}
\textara{hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Are they necessary? TeX Live doesn't supply them as far as I can tell. However, there are outline fonts. What are you trying to do exactly? You don't say which LaTeX compiler you have, so suggesting a fancier or less fancy one would be difficult. But note that you can always use an online compiler, if you can't install one locally. Then you have TeX Live available with `allrunes` and everything else installed out-of-the-box.

Comment: Any online compiler you would suggest? I'm using an app called tex writer, and it needs .tfm files. I'm also not too familiar with loading fonts, so if I'm saying something that doesn't make sense tell me.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example demonstrating what you're trying to do? Overleaf and ShareLaTeX are popular online options.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{allrunes}
\begin{document}
\textara{HELLO}

\end{document}

Comment: Please use the 'edit' link on your question to add the code there. Highlight and press `{}` or use ctrl+k to format it as code.

Comment: Oh, I see, the TFMs are generated from the MFs in order to use the PFBs. Since this is done automatically on-the-fly by `pdflatex` (for example), I'd assume it should work for you, if the fonts are installed correctly and you have an ordinary installation of TeX. (You don't say anything about this, except that whatever it is, you are determined to stick with it or have to stick with it or something.)

Comment: Sorry about not getting the formatting right on the edit but I don't have a control key (on mobile as I said before) and I didn't see anything marked as {}. Maybe if I knew the markup flag but i'm new here. Really all I'm asking here is if I can get the .tfm files from allrunes. If you could do me a big favour and grab them from your installation that'd be awesome. I am using a mobile app so I don't have anything close to a normal installation.

Comment: Most TFM files are created as part of support packages, but these aren't. There are no TFMs. As I said above, they are created on-the-fly as needed. So the PFB is combined with the MF, which is used to make the TFM.

Comment: The result of compiling your file appears to be what looks like a capital H.

Comment: Werner probably has them, though.